# How to align text inside textfield to bottom in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want the text inside `TextField` to the very bottom.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Home());

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical(y: -0.0),
            decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using `textAlignVertical` but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share any image as your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `contentPadding`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Home());

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical(y: -0.0),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0), //here
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```